# How to quickly discriminate between interfaces with non-overlapping properties

Tags: typescript, strict, type-deduction

In typescript, I commonly have a variable with a type like:

```js
const variable: { a: string } | { b: number };
```

When I want to check what shape the variable has, I usually want to do

```js
if (variable.a !== undefined) {
  // do stuff
}
else {
  // do stuff
```

However in strict mode, typescript throws a type error at `variable.a` because `variable` is not known to have the property `a`. To get around this, I usually cast to `any` like `(variable as any).a !== undefined`. However typescript doesn't treat this as a type guard and doesn't narrow the type of `variable`.

Is there a "proper" way of doing this check in typescript when in strict mode (without making a custom type guard)?

Some examples I've tried (which, unfortunately, also throw type errors):

- `typeof variable.a !== 'undefined'`
- `variable.hasOwnProperty('a')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript type guard through in operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422187/typescript-type-guard-through-in-operator)

Comment: @tehhowch while it's possible the answer to my question is the same as the answer to that question, these two questions introduce very different scenarios. In that question, the poster *already knows what they are trying to do (in that case, use the `in` operator)*. In this question, the poster does not know what they are trying to do. I don't think someone searching for an answer to *this* question would find *that* question (I certainly didn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to discriminate in this case would be an `in` type guard:

```
declare const variable: { a: string } | { b: number };


if ('a' in variable) {
    variable.a
}
else {
    variable.b
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! I've been doing hacky work-arounds forever and it just occurred to me to search S.O. for a better solution -- but I didn't really expect there to be one. This makes me so happy!